# In OSPF, can I have an NSSA router act as the DR for the ABR router in area 0?

Tags: ospf

I have a router in an NSSA area attached, via an ABR, to area 0; this is done through a broadcast link with a point-to-point address (31 bit prefix), so there are basically only two routers on this network segment.

Is it ok to have the NSSA router act as the DR for the link between the ABR and itself? Or should it only be the ABR router that is in Area 0 that acts as the BR for the link between the NSSA router and itself?

*NOTE
No please allow me to clear up any confusion on the wording, because there are people out there that get easily confused by the words, VERY easily confused.

When I say, "I have a router in an NSSA area attached, via an ABR, to Area 0" What I mean *exactly* is that there is a router that has all interfaces in the NSSA area, and no interfaces in any other area. It is attached to some cables that run through some switches and ultimately connects to a router that has interfaces in more than one area. This type of router is known as an ABR. This ABR has one of its interfaces in Area 0, and another interface in the aforementioned NSSA area.

Comment: Your question is still a little confusing.  *...this is done through a multipoint link with a point-to-point address.*  Do you mean your interfaces are configured as point to multipoint?  Or point to point?

Comment: @Ron, you actually cleared up my confusion on the the resource usage between the DR/BDR in another post of mine, which actually formed the basis for  this question. I now know it would be useless to have the NSSA router have perform the role of DR, because that will not lighten the resource load for the BDR, which would the ABR in the question.

Comment: Actually, that was me, not @RonTrunk, to whom you are replying. In any case, the scenario you describe in this question would not use DR/BDR because it is the wrong link type for that.

Comment: multipoint with a 31 bit address; the kind of addressing used in point-to-point links

Comment: An OSPF multipoint network does not use DR/BDR. Only the OSPF network types with the word "broadcast" (broadcast or non-broadcast) use DR/BDR. It is that simple. Please do not try to take a network exam with the idea that OSPF multipoint networks use DR/BDR because you will get that question wrong. It does not matter in the least what addressing you use on the network; you could use `/24` for an OSPF point-to-point network, and it is still an OSPF point-to-point network that does not use DR/BDR.

Comment: My bad. I meant 'broadcast' instead of multipoint.

Comment: @Octavian Since you've changed the sense of your question, all the comments and answers no longer make sense.  Perhaps it might be better to create a new question.

Comment: @ the Rons, I've already answered it. Perhaps since there are so many comments, they should just be moved to 'conversation'

Comment: @Octavian Sadly, SE doesn't work that way.  The best way for others to understand your question and learn from your answer is to make things clear by creating a new question and deleting this one.  Future readers shouldn't have to plow through all this to get to the answer.

Comment: I know the Ron Maupin will quickly throw  long back and forth comment section into the conversation. It would actually make sense to do it here where is an actual solution to an actual problem, even if i had to answer it myself. MOST people can look beyond a minor syntactical error because most people aren't petty. So it would be a good question for most people.

Comment: If you are happy with this question, and the way it makes you look, along with the down votes and damage to your reputation, then I am happy to let it stand as is. It is actually in your best interest to simply delete this question, removing the down votes and everything else, then asking and answering a proper question. You may even find you gain some reputation through up votes to a good question and answer. If you want to simply be obstinate, we can accommodate you.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The router in the NSSA area can take the role of the DR with no averse consequences. That is because in this scenario, the are only two routers on the broadcast link, as it has a 31-bit prefix.

Both routers will consume the same amount of resources and both routers will exchange the topologies with only each other. So since the same amount of resources are consumed by the router acting as the DR as are consumed by the router acting as the BDR, there is no advantage gained in specifying the ABR as the BDR. Therefore there is also no advantage gained in specifying the NSSA (non-ABR router) as the DR.

Comment: This answer is incorrect because multipoint OSPF networks simply do hot have DRs. If you believe otherwise, despite, and contrary to, the RFC and Cisco documentation, please share the source documentation describing that with us.

Comment: I guess I will as soon as you tell me what a 'multipoint OSPF network' is

Comment: In OSPF parlance, a multipoint network is an OSPF `point-to-multipoint` type of network. That is what you will lead any network engineer to understand when you speak of multipoint OSPF networks, as you have seen here, on NESE. We sometimes have problems with novices and the misuse of terminology as you demonstrated, and we put the question on hold as **unclear what you're asking** until we can determine the correct terminology. You would do well to delete this question, then ask a new question, as it would remove your down votes, and you could provide a correct answer to a correct question.

Comment: You may even get some up votes on both the correct question and correct answer

Comment: I beleve that the term 'multipoint', when used by itself, refers to a network that resembles a 'broadcast' network. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/multipoint  https://techdifferences.com/difference-between-point-to-point-and-multipoint-connection.html https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HVLAN

Comment: "_Multipoint_" is a term of art that means something specific in the context of OSPF. The specific context in which a term is used can completely change the meaning of the term. For example, the term "_broadband_" has a specific original meaning to an engineer, but for government purposes, it means something completely different. In fact, to the government, a "_baseband_" circuit could be classified as "_broadband_", even though it is not "_broadband_" to an engineer.

Comment: Can you provide any documentation to back-up that claim?

Comment: A simple search turn up the different meanings of "_broadband_", depending on the context. In fact [the Wikipedia Broadband article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadband) explains that it depends on the context.

Comment: And, a simple Google search for `multipoint network` turns up a lot of hits, almost all of which concern point-to-multipoint networks, even the ones that say something like "_**What is multipoint network?**_": "_The Point-to-Multipoint topology (also called star topology or simply P2MP) is a common network architecture for outdoor wireless networks to connect multiple locations to one single central location._"

Comment: I am of course speaking only about the term 'mulitpoint', The term 'broadband' is totally irrelevant here and it seems only to serve as a distraction. I provided an example via documentation for my **artful** usage of the term 'multipoint'.

Comment: Just treat all of this as a learning experience and understand that in the context of OSPF, there are a few network types (detailed in [the image in my answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pi8Dp.png)), and the use of the term "_multipoint_" in the context of OSPF has a specific meaning. If you aspire to take network exams and get certifications, you really need to embrace the terminology.

Comment: I would love to use the terminology correctly. Can you provide some documentation on the example you keep trying to correct me on? The way you used the word **artufl** is very telling; what was wrong with my **artful** interpretation? I made it pretty clear through the extended explanation what i meant. If I was using the term wrong, then why is my wrong worse than your wrong? Why couldn't you just provide a helpful answer to begin with instead of trolling me? To troll a person with a genuine problem doesn't seem to be very fruitful or serve any grander purpose.

Comment: I wasn't trolling you. We were trying to answer the question as asked. We do not change the meaning of a question because it will confuse later readers. The point of SE sites is that they form an archive to which people in the future can refer. We are not mind readers, and You kept referring to multipoint and point-to-point (of which point-to-multipoint is a variant). What you did was completely change the question, which is really bad form and strongly frowned upon for SE sites. The proper thing to do when completely changing the meaning of a question is to simply ask a different question.

Comment: What I was supposed to do is to place the question On-Hold until the question was rehabilitated (as I tried on the first version of your question), but I tried to answer it as asked, then you completely changed the meaning of the question. We have bent over backwards to try to help you, but you seem to radiate hostility, and you seem to think we are targeting you for some reason. That is simply not true. We have tried to help you at every step.

Comment: If you had just relaxed and cooperated with the process, we would have come to the correct question and answer much earlier, but you resisted our efforts to help you at every step. For the next time, please help us help you, and you will get what you need much faster.

Comment: I changed one word; a word that seemed to cause a bit of confusion for you. Your confusion appeared to me to be manufactured, hence the feeling of 'radiated hostility' in return.

Comment: Think of it this way: suppose you wanted to ask about OSPF, but you substituted the word "_EIGRP_" instead of "_OSPF_". Wouldn't you expect that we would try to tell you that what you are asking does not make sense? That is really the same thing here. You asked about one network type, but you really meant a different network type, yet you wanted us to read your mind and give you an answer for what you meant, not what you wrote. It simply doesn't work that way.

Comment: We really do try to be helpful, but what a lot of people who ask questions here forget is that we are all volunteers. Some people seem to think they are owed an answer (I have been told several times that it is my job to serve someone). When people who participate here get rude and abusive, they often find their questions or answers ignored or voted down by the rest of the users. In a way, someone asking a question is asking for time and knowledge (money) from us, and people who are not treated with respect are naturally reluctant to give that. SE asks that everyone, above all, "_be nice_".

Answer (score 1):

### New answer for the edited question:

> Is it ok to have the NSSA router act as the DR for the link between
> the ABR and itself? Or should it only be the ABR router that is in
> Area 0 that acts as the BR for the link between the NSSA router and
> itself?

In such a situation, there are several possibilities:

- **Everything at the default:** It doesn't matter which device is the DR and which is the BDR because each router will form a full
  adjacency with the other router.
- **One router with the priority set to `0` (never be DR or BDR):** It doesn't matter which device is the DR because each router will form a
  full adjacency with the other router.
- **The broadcast interfaces configured as OSPF point-to-point interfaces:** There will be no DR/BDR, and each router will form a full adjacency with the other
  router.

In any scenario, each of the two routers on the network will need to form a full adjacency with the other router on the link. In such a case, it would be normal to configure the interfaces on the routers to set the OSPF network type to be point-to-point using the `ip ospf network point-to-point` interface command because there is no real need for a DR/BDR.

The idea behind using a DR/BDR is for links where there are multiple OSPF routers to prevent the need for each router on the link from having to form a full adjacency with every other router on the link. That can quickly get out of hand (exponentially). By using a DR, then every router only needs to create one full adjacency with the DR (and one with a BDR, if there is a BDR, which is not a requirement). That can drastically cut back on the number of adjacencies (router resources) and OSPF control traffic required on a broadcast link.

If there are only two routers on a link, then it makes sense to set the OSPF network type to point-to-point to let them simply form full adjacencies with each other, which is going to happen in any scenario. In any of the scenarios, the router resources used for adjacencies will be the same, and eliminating the need for DR/BDR makes sense because that is one less thing for a router to do.

You can even use an OSPF point-to-point network on smaller prefixes, e.g. `/24`, if there are only two OSPF router in the network.

---

### Original answer for the original question:

Your question is moot because there will be no DR/BDR for point-to-point or point-to-multipoint links. There will be no DR in your scenario.

[*OSPF Design Guide*](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/open-shortest-path-first-ospf/7039-1.html)

> **Adjacencies on Point-to-Point Interfaces**
>
> OSPF will always form an adjacency with the neighbor on the other side
> of a point-to-point interface such as point-to-point serial lines.
> There is no concept of DR or BDR. The state of the serial interfaces
> is point to point.

-and-

> **Point-to-Multipoint Interfaces**
>
> An OSPF point-to-multipoint interface is defined as a numbered
> point-to-point interface having one or more neighbors. This concept
> takes the previously discussed point-to-point concept one step
> further. Administrators do not have to worry about having multiple
> subnets for each point-to-point link. The cloud is configured as one
> subnet. This should work well for people who are migrating into the
> point-to-point concept with no change in IP addressing on the cloud.
> Also, they would not have to worry about DRs and neighbor statements.
> OSPF point-to-multipoint works by exchanging additional link-state
> updates that contain a number of information elements that describe
> connectivity to the neighboring routers.

Below are the OSPF network types, including the Cisco extensions. Please note the multipoint links (what you ask about in the question) do not elect DR/BDR, which is what makes your question moot.

OSPF elects DR/BDR on *broadcast* or *non-broadcast* links:

[image]

---

Perhaps you will believe [*RFC 2328, OSPF Version 2*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2328#page-225) (emphasis is mine):

> C.6 Point-to-MultiPoint network parameters
>
> On Point-to-MultiPoint networks, it may be necessary to configure the
> set of neighbors that are directly reachable over the
> Point-to-MultiPoint network. Each neighbor is identified by its IP
> address on the Point-to-MultiPoint network. **Designated Routers are
> not elected on Point-to-MultiPoint networks**, so the Designated
> Router eligibility of configured neighbors is undefined.
>
> Alternatively, neighbors on Point-to-MultiPoint networks may be
> dynamically discovered by lower-level protocols such as Inverse ARP
> ([[Ref14](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2328#ref-Ref14)]).

Comment: This answer doesn't help at all, in fact it confuses things for you even further. There IS a DR/BDR selection in this scenario because it is a mulltipoint link, as stated directly in the question in the first sentence; " multipoint link with a point-to-point address (31 bit prefix)". So a multi-point link with a 31 bit address still has an election.

Comment: I guess you didn't read the part about point-to-multipoint links where is explains: "_Also, they would not have to worry about DRs and neighbor statements._" I really do not understand why it is so hard for you to understand that point-to-point and point-to-multipoint links **do not have DR/BDR**. It is all over the Cisco documentation. You simply need to read it. I have been doing OSPF on Cisco devices since probably before you were born. Ron Trunk is a CCIE, and I doubt you will find anyone here that agrees with your position.

Comment: @ the Rons. Who is talking about point-to-multipoint? Where did I ever mention that this is a point-to-multipoint?

Comment: Your question is predicated on that: "_this is done through a multipoint link with a point-to-point address_"

Comment: @Octavian It seems you are casually using terms like "multipoint" and "point to point" that have a special meaning for OSPF.  You now appear to be describing a broadcast network.  These terms have special meaning to OSPF and they affect the answer to your question. That's why your question is confusing.   We're trying to get clarification so we can give you the answer you're looking for.

Comment: BTW the choice of subnet mask has no bearing on the interface type, and therefore neither on the answer.

Comment: @Octavian Also, you seem to lack a lot of respect to those who answer your questions. We're just trying to help you, there's no reason to be rude about it.

Comment: @ the Rons, respect is a two way street

Comment: @Octavian, that was Cown that wrote that. We have been nothing but polite to you, yet you have been less than polite in return. We have gone far out of our way to try to help you, but you seem to have an incorrect idea stuck in your head, and I seriously doubt that you will find any support for your position here.

Comment: My bad. I meant 'broadcast' instead of multipoint.

Comment: @Octavian, that is the reason your previous question was put On-Hold as **unclear what you're asking**,and why this one nearly shared that fate. We need an answerable question, and your original question had two incompatible features to it and was actually unanswerable as asked. You have now completely changed the question, and all the comments and the answer that I provided that is completely correct for the original question have no meaning. I suggest you delete this question and ask your new question in a new question. The down votes you have attracted on this question will then disappear.

Comment: "If there are only two routers on a link, then it makes sense to set the OSPF network type to point-to-point to let them simply form full adjacencies with each other, which is going to happen in any scenario. In any of the scenarios, the router resources used for adjacencies will be the same, and eliminating the need for DR/BDR makes sense because that is one less thing for a router to do."  This was helpful, thanks for that advice